# Is there a good way to create a server on ipad? (Node.js or Jetty)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jetty, hybrid-mobile-app

I'd like to build an offline Hybrid app using angularjs, can I create a rest server on local ipad? (Node.js or Jetty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really create a server on an iPad -- it wouldn't be accessible by other apps on the device (which is what it sounds like you're wanting to do).

With a hybrid app, instead consider using local storage api to store and access data when you're offline. You can write a service in angularjs to handle data access, in which case you can use local storage or an actual web service, depending on whether you're actually online or not. By abstracting it within a service, the rest of your app need not know or care about whether you're online or offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own api's using Apiary http://apiary.io/

As soon as you define the api and it will be available live with the stubs that you define. Try exploring this its awesome.